# How to create a FOLDER in a SPECIFIC directory

Tags: c++, windows, directory, system, command-prompt

I just want to create a folder in a specific directory, but the solution below doesn't work. Any ideas please ?

```
std::string userFolder="mkdir ";
userFolder+=name;
system("cd ../data/user");
system(userFolder.c_str());
```

Comment: The `system` function starts a new shell in a new process. Commands like `cd` will affect that shell and process only, not the one calling `system`. Use [the standard filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) instead.

Comment: You cannot change the programs working directory using a `system()` call.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `system()`, a new instance of the OS command processor is launched in its own process. Each process has its own working directory. So, commands like `cd` don't work the way you expect across process boundaries.

What you can do, though, is execute multiple commands with 1 `system()` call, eg:

```
std::string cmds = "cd ../data/user && mkdir " + name;
system(cmds.c_str());
```

But, it would be best not to rely on that at all.  You can specify the complete path in 1 command, eg:

```
std::string cmd = "mkdir ../data/user/" + name;
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Which would then be better handled using the standard [`std::filesystem::create_directory()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) function in the `<filesystem>` library, eg:

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

fs::create_directory(fs::path("../data/user") / name);
```